# Confusion in a Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently studying and tyring to understand the proof of the derangement of descent sets, and in this particular paper:

http://emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_16/PDF/v16i1r32.pdf

I am reading the proof to the **theorem 2.3** (on page **5**). I am stuck at understanding few parts to the proof of **theorem 2.3:**

**Question 1:** Why is $\binom{n}{a_1,....,a_k}$ the coefficient of the expansion $$1+(\sum x_i)+(\sum x_i)^2+\cdots, \text{furthermore why is }1+(\sum x_i)+(\sum x_i)^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x_1-\cdots-x_k}$$

**Question 2:** How come the identity $|D_j(\alpha)|=|D_j(\alpha)|+|D_j(a_1,...,a_{j-1},a_j-1,a_{j+1},...a_k)|$ hold, furthermore how did this lead to the recursion $F_{j-1}(\mathbb{x})=(1+x_j)F_j(\mathbb{x})?$

I would really appreciate some clear clarification to why the above holds, as I just cant seem to understand why it is the case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can help with question 1: The coefficient $$\frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!\cdots a_k!}=\binom{n}{a_1,\cdots,a_k}$$ of $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ in the expansion of $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i\right)^n$$ is just the [multinomial theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) and the series expansion of $$\frac{1}{1-\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i}$$ is just the Taylor series of $$\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+u^2+\cdots$$ for $$u=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i$$.

Comment: Thank you, but hmm I am confused with the generating functions part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which part you mean, specifically. All of the results I gave you are quite well known.  Are you referring to the paper?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, yes the second question, which is also in the proof of the theorem 23 page 5 of the paper. Your answer yes, my confusion for question 1 is completely gone now thanks to you, but second question I am still having a hard time figuring out.

Comment: I will have a look at the paper when I have a moment and get back to you. I might need to sit down with it for a while in order to assimilate the information.

Comment: Yes that would be great, because I am really stuck at understanding that part. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\x{\boldsymbol{x}}$
**The following is my *soft* interpretation of the part of the paper in question. Please see the link in the question for more details.**

First off it is a good idea to establish some meaning of the generating function

$$F_0(\x)=\frac{1}{1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j}=1+\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right)+\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right)^{\!\!2}+\cdots$$

in this context.

To understand this let's look at just one of the terms

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right)^{\!\!n}$$

which has the interpretation of distributing the $n$ elements of $[n]$ into $k$ subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_k$. Each successive factor $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k$ in the product $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k)^n$ represents the possible assignment of each successive element of $[n]$ to the $k$ subsets.

So, the coefficient of $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ in the expansion of this  term is $n!/(a_1!\cdots a_k!)$ which is the number of ways to distribute elements of $[n]$ into $k$ subsets (or blocks) $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ of respective sizes $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_k$.

In the paper these blocks *always* have elements of $[n]$ in descending order left to right within each block. Also, the blocks and themselves appear in left-to-right order $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$, therefore displaying as a permutation of $[n]$. These permutations of $[n]$ clearly have descents between adjacent pairs of the first $a_1$ elements elements, the next $a_2$ elements and so forth. The only *possible* ascents positions being between $a_1$ and $a_1+1$, $a_2$ and $a_2+1$ etc.

So we see that $(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k)^n$ is interpreted by the paper as generating permutations of $[n]$ with descents in the aforementioned prescribed positions. Hence $F_0(\x)$ generates all such permutations for *all possible* $n$. Granted it only really makes sense for terms $n\ge k$ otherwise there are more blocks than elements but we will not concern ourselves with that here.

The paper calls another (as yet unknown) generating function $F_j(\x)$ which generates permutations of a given block type $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ with no fixed points in blocks $A_1$ to $A_{j}$. It is important to note that any descending block $A_j$ can have *at most* 1 fixed point simply *because* it is *descending*. It is also worth noting that the permutations generated by $F_j(\x)$ include those with no fixed points in blocks $A_{j+1}$ to $A_k$ (i.e. derangements) *and* all permutations with their fixed point combinations only in blocks $A_{j+1}$ to $A_k$.

The paper establishes a lovely bijection which takes *any* permutation length $n$ of type $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ generated by $F_{j}(\x)$ and inserts a fixed point in block $A_{j}$ to give a permutation length $n+1$. Since such a permutation has a fixed point in block $A_j$  it must be generated by $F_{j-1}(\x)$ and it is represented by the contribution $x_jF_j(\x)$ to $F_{j-1}(\x)$. But, of course, a length $n+1$ permutation generated by $F_{j-1}(\x)$ may *also* include *all* of the length $n+1$ permutations generated by $F_j(\x)$, as these have *no* fixed points in blocks $A_1$ to $A_j$, this adds a contribution $F_j(\x)$ to $F_{j-1}(\x)$.

Hence, to summarise, we have described permutations length $n+1$ that have either no fixed points or fixed points in blocks to the right of $A_{j-1}$ (these are generated by $F_{j-1}(\x)$) as the sum of permutations length $n+1$ that have a leftmost fixed point in block $A_j$ (generated by $x_jF_{j}(\x)$) and permutations of length $n+1$ that either have no fixed points or fixed points in blocks to the right of $A_j$ (generated by $F_{j}(\x)$). Or simply:

$$F_{j-1}(\x)=F_j(\x)+x_jF_j(\x)=(1+x_j)F_j(\x)\, .$$

Iterating:

$$F_0(\x)=(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_j)F_j(\x)\, .$$

This gives:

$$\begin{align}F_j(\x)&=\frac{F_0(\x)}{(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_j)}\\[1ex]&=\frac{F_0(\x)}{(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_j)\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right)}\end{align}$$

The result of Theorem 2.1 is a special case of this for $j=k$:

$$\begin{align}F_k(\x)&=\frac{F_0(\x)}{(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_k)}\\[1ex]&=\frac{1}{(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_k)\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j\right)}\end{align}$$

this is the generating function for permutations with no fixed points and descents in *at least* the aforementioned prescribed positions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort for writing up this solution. Just a quick question, where does the term $x^jF_j(x)$ come from? This is the only part I seem to be stuck at.

Comment: @Aurora Borealis, thanks! Every term in $F_j(x)$ of the form $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_j^{a_j}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ represents permutations with no fixed points in blocks $A_1$ to $A_j$. By using the bijection in the paper to put a fixed point in block $A_j$ for permutations of $F_j(x)$ we extend the size of block $A_j$ by $1$ (and leave other blocks unaffected), thus replacing $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_j^{a_j}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ in $F_j(x)$ with $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_j^{a_j+1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$. Factor this extra $x_j$ out to give $x_jF_j(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was honestly very helpful. Now I will study it from the beginning all over again, and make sure I 100% get it.

Comment: Well, thank you for the question. I wouldn't have read that interesting paper otherwise. :)

Comment: So I now understood everything EXCEPT the part where we says in the paper $\binom{n}{a_1,...,a_k} $is the coefficient in the expansion of $1+\sum x_i+(\sum x_i)^2+.... $I get that it is the expansion for $(\sum x_i)^n,$ but why is it the coefficients of $x_1^{a_1}...a_k^{a_k} $in the expansion of $1+\sum x_i+(\sum x_i)^2+....?$ Because from how I understand, $1+\sum x_i+(\sum x_i)^2+.... \ne (\sum x_i)^n$. I would appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: $\binom{n}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}$ is the coefficient of $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ in $F_0(x)=1+\left(\sum x_i\right)+\left(\sum x_i\right)^2+\cdots$ *because* $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k}$ *only comes from the term* $\left(\sum x_i\right)^n$ in $F_0(x)$, not from any of the others.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply,  so I want to ask, what is the significance of the term $1+\sum x_i +(\sum x_i)^2 + ....$ if they do not contribute to the coefficients?

Comment: It is so we can do all that stuff with the bijection between permutations on $[n+1]$ and $[n]$ to give recurrence $F_{j-1}(x)=(1+x_j)F_j(x)$. We need the whole expression for this.

Comment: I understand everything, but I still have a problem understanding my confusion regarding this problem coefficients and the relation to the expansion of the series $(\sum x_i)^n$, and how we can consider $1+\sum x_i+(\sum x_i)^2+...$

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, yes I will email you.